# Calling a function in another class doens't work

Tags: php

This is a quick noob question. I'm trying to call a function in another class but it doens't work. Thanks in advance

```
** main.php **
require_once("../push/push.php"); 
new APNS_Push($config);
start();


** push.php **

class APNS_Push
{
private $fp = NULL;
private $server;
private $certificate;
private $passphrase;

function __construct($config)
{
    $this->server = $config['server'];
    $this->certificate = $config['certificate'];
    $this->passphrase = $config['passphrase'];

    // Create a connection to the database.
    $this->pdo = new PDO(
        'mysql:host=' . $config['db']['host'] . ';dbname=' . $config['db']['dbname'], 
        $config['db']['username'], 
        $config['db']['password'],
        array());


    // If there is an error executing database queries, we want PDO to
    // throw an exception.
    $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // We want the database to handle all strings as UTF-8.
    $this->pdo->query('SET NAMES utf8');
}

// This is the main loop for this script. It polls the database for new
// messages, sends them to APNS, sleeps for a few seconds, and repeats this
// forever (or until a fatal error occurs and the script exits).
function start()
{
    //writeToLog('Connecting to ' . $this->server);

    if (!$this->connectToAPNS())
        exit;


        // Do at most 20 messages at a time. Note: we send each message in
        // a separate packet to APNS. It would be more efficient if we 
        // combined several messages into one packet, but this script isn't
        // smart enough to do that. ;-)

        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM push_queue WHERE time_sent IS NULL LIMIT 25');
        $stmt->execute();
        $messages = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        $deletedIds = array();

        foreach ($messages as $message)
        {
            echo 's'; 
            if ($this->sendNotification($message->message_id, $message->device_token, $message->payload))
            {
                //$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('UPDATE push_queue SET time_sent = NOW() WHERE message_id = ?');

                $name = $message->name; 
                echo $name; 
                $value = '1'; 
                //$this->pdo->query('UPDATE users SET needsUpdate = '$value' WHERE username='$name'');

                //$stmt->execute(array($message->message_id));

                 $deletedIds[] = $message->message_id;

                //$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM push_queue WHERE message_id = ?');
                //$stmt->execute(array($message->message_id));

            }
            else  // failed to deliver
            {
                $this->reconnectToAPNS();
            }
        }

        //Delete the chunk of messages.
        $this->pdo->query('DELETE FROM push_queue WHERE message_id IN ('.implode(',', $deletedIds).')');


        //echo 'success'; 

        unset($messages);           

}
```

Comment: Maybe tell us which function is giving you the error.

Comment: You haven't set $this->pdo as a class property. You need a `private $pdo;` in your property declarations.

Comment: Could this question be more vague? This isn't Where's Waldo. Give us the error message at least.

Comment: There isn't any error. Nothing happens? How do I set a prive $pdo? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I see a missing `}`.  I added that at the end of the class, and the below worked fine.

```
$myPush = new APNS_Push($config);
$myPush->start();
```

Comment: Right, the script handling of the class was missing the proper instantiation, as well.